# What quotient space of a non Hausdorff space can be a Hausdorff space?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

A line with two Origins is a simple example of a quotient space of Hausdorff space that is not Hausdorff. What quotient of a non Hausdorff space (or maybe non Kolmogorov) can be a Hausdorff(or Kolmogorov) space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give a specific example relating to the one that you mentioned yourself: Let $X$ be the line with doubled origin (not Haudorff) and denote by $O_1$ and $O_2$ the two origins in $X$. Let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation generated by stipulating $O_1 \sim O_2$, that is:
$$x \sim y\qquad \iff \qquad x = y \quad \text{or} \quad x,y \in \{O_1, O_2\}.$$
Then $X / {\sim}$ is homeomorphic to the ordinary affine line and, in particular, Hausdorff. In fact, the affine line is the “Hausdorffization” (mentioned by PrudiiArca) of the line with doubled orign.

In the comments, the OP asked for examples where the Hausdorffization identifies more points than just two. If $X$ is an [irreducible space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperconnected_space), then its Hausdorffization collapses to a single point. Examples of irreducible spaces include:

1. Any set with its codiscrete topology.
2. Any linear order with its [Alexandrov topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology).
3. An [algebraic variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_variety) with its [Zariski topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_topology).

Comment: Thanks. More like "de non Hausdorffization". Is there an example where uncountably many groups ("pairs") of elements are identified?

Comment: Thanks for the interesting comment regarding irreducible spaces.

Answer (score 4):

Take any topological space $X$ (Hausdorff or not) and consider on $X$ the equivalence relation $\sim$ such that $(\forall x,y\in X):x\sim y$. Since $X/\sim$ is a singleton, it is Hausdorff.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed a simple structure. Is there a some other example where the quotient space is not countable?

Comment: The line about the final topology can be removed. Why did you write it?

Comment: Yes. On $\mathbb R\times\{0,1\}$ consider this topology: $A$ is open if it can be written as $A^\star\times\{0,1\}$, where $A^\star$ is an open subset of $\Bbb R$. Consider on $\mathbb R\times\{0,1\}$ the equivalence relation $\sim$ defined by $(x,a)\sim(y,b)$ if and only if $x=y$. Then $(\Bbb R^2\times\{0,1\})/\sim$, endowed with the final metric with respect to the natural projection, is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ (with its usual topology), which is Hausdorff and not countable.

Comment: @JensRenders So that there was no ambiguity about the topology that I was using on $X/\sim$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I feel like your joking... we are talking about the space with one point right? What other topology would you use?

Comment: Yes, I understand that it feels as if I was joking. But I wasn't. When I wrote my previous comment I had already forgotten that $X/\sim$ was a singleton. You are right, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn any topological space into a Hausdorff space by a process called [hausdorffization](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Hausdorffization). Basically you take the quotient by the minimal equivalence relation making the quotient a Hausdorff-space. This is in fact the free construction of this sort and exhibits $\mathsf{Haus}$ as reflective subcategory of $\mathsf{Top}$. In particular every map from $X$ to some Hausdorff-space $Y$ factors uniquely over $X_\text{Haus}$.

Comment: Thanks. It seems kind of like how one defines a new bijective function onto an injective function's range by construction. Is there some other kind of equivalence relation that does this?

Comment: What do you mean by other equivalence relation? Such a construction is quite common see for example the construction of the free group as quotient of the free monoid by the minimal equivalence relation making it a group. If you mean another relation turning a topological space into a Hausdorff space, you can take any equivalence relation containing that minimal one (as quotients of Hausdorff spaces are Hausdorff). Of cause this is not free anymore. You can do the hausdorffication with an equivalence relation on all the maps from X into Hausdorff spaces Y, but with my limited knowledge of set

Comment: theory I find this construction rather shady, since it quantifies over a class.